# vue.js method return keeps updating

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to Vue js so sorry for the stupid question. I am using a v-data-table to loop through an array. I need the return from a method to not change, but when the method runs it changes for every row.

I have tried a computed value but for some reason you can't pass a variable into a computed field?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-data-table
      :items="responseData"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <td :key="props.item.tmdbId" class="text-xs-right">
          This: {{checkMovieExists(props.item.tmdbId)}}
        </td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      allMovies: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get("XXXX")
      .then(response => (this.allMovies = response.data)) 
  },
  methods: {
    checkMovieExists(strMovieTmdbId){
      this.allMovies.forEach(movie => {
        if (movie.tmdbId == strMovieTmdbId) {
          return "Exists"
        }
      });                
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: "I need the return from a method to not change" What do you mean by this? Do you want the method to only fire once for each item and then not again if the data for the items change?

Comment: `checkMovieExists` function essentially returns `undefined` - the result of `forEach`. If you want to find an item, use `Array.find` instead.

Comment: Also, you're binding `responseData` to the `items` prop of the data table component, but you don't define `responseData` anywhere...

Comment: Sorry the ResponseData is actually from another part of the code which has been removed. This basically returns a list of movies based off of a search.
What I want is the method to fire once when it runs, if that makes sense? So each row will have a different value.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what exactly you're looking to accomplish. The first obvious issue, as raina77ow mentioned, is that your `checkMovieExists` method doesn't return anything, so nothing will be rendered in that method call in the template. This does seem like something you should use a computed property for (it's usually a code-smell to directly call a method in the template instead of using a computed). I'd suggest editing your code example to make it an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computed properties are calculated based on the internal state only. They are special in the sense that they only have to be recalculated whenever the internal state on which they depend is changed. They don't accept any arguments, because that would make them rely on more than reactivity of your state, which defeats this caching mechanism. You could use a computed property to process the data you got from the api and loop over that instead, but lets ignore that for now.

As pointed out in the comments, the problem with your method is that you are using a `forEach` loop with a function, and return in the inner function. The outer function does not return anything, and thus the return value is `undefined`. There are several ways you can do this, but I think using [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) works best in your case. You pass this method a function which is executed for each item in the array you are invoking it on. The entire thing returns `true` if any of these invocations returns `true`, and otherwise it returns `false`.

```
movieExists(strMovieTmdbId){
  return this.allMovies.some(movie => movie.tmdbId === strMovieTmdbId);
}
```

You will notice that I return a boolean here. I do this because your function is called `XYZExists`. We can use this boolean response to output something appropriate in the template.

```
  <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
    <td :key="props.item.tmdbId" class="text-xs-right">
      This: {{ checkMovieExists(props.item.tmdbId) ? 'Exists' : '' }}
    </td>
  </template>
```

---

As far as the use of scoped slots goes, I believe you are doing it mostly correct as long as `this.allMovies` is something like:

```
[
  {
    tmdbId: 1
  },
  {
    tmdbId: 2
  }
]
```

Keep in mind that the `items` slot renders an entire row, not just one cell. You will need to surround it with `<tr> ... </tr>`.

---

As thanksd commented below, using this method may cause performance issues if the template is rerendered a lot. After all, each time the method is invoked, it looks through an entire array, for every item in that array.

Instead we can prepare the data using a computed property. Since you only assign data once in the mounted hook, your computed property should only be calculated once. Of course, you should then avoid mutating `this.allMovies` to prevent recalculation of your computed property.

You can keep the method we created earlier, but instead of using `this.allMovies` to render the data, we are going to use this method to calculate the data... once. We use a map to create an extra property that contains the result of the method.

```
computed: {
  preparedData () {
    return this.responseData.map(
      row => {
        return {
          ...row,
          exists: this.movieExists(row.tmdbId)
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Now, instead of using `responseData` (whatever that is), we use `preparedData` to render the table. Since we now have a precalculated property `exists` on each row, we can just check `props.item.exists` instead of having to invoke a function. When the template is rerendered, as long as `responseData` stays constant, we use the cached version of `preparedData`.

```
<v-data-table
  :items="preparedData"
  class="elevation-1"
>
  <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
    <td :key="props.item.tmdbId" class="text-xs-right">
      This: {{ props.item.exists ? 'Exists' : '' }}
    </td>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: This is probably in the right direction of what they are looking for. However, your solution still calls a method from the template for each item in the array (still unclear to me if this is what they are trying to prevent, but either way it is a code smell). This means any time *any* data bound to the template changes, the `checkMovieExists` method will be fired for each item. If `allMovies`, or `responseData` are very big, this could introduce a performance issue. Would be better to have a computed object which maps tmdbIDs to a boolean value for whether they exist in the `allMovies` array.

Comment: Or i think better yet would be to create a computed that was a copy of the `responseData`, but with an `exists` property calculated for each item. Then pass that the to table component instead. Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/vdero1j3/

Comment: I've expanded the answer a bit based on your feedback.

Comment: That worked a treat, thank you so much and for spending the time to explain it :-D